# File Attachements with PHP5 SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm writing some code to talk to a web service via WSDL-SOAP. I'm using php5's native soap implementation. So far so good.

However I now need to download files as "attachments" over soap. The interwebs is mysteriously silent on how to do this. Surely its possible or the PHP docs would mention it as a limitation ? :\ I did this a few years ago with Pear soap but would really prefer to use the native Soap implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122292/php-soap-client-that-understands-multi-part-messages/1123887#1123887). Perhaps this may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Considering [this discussion](http://www.nabble.com/SOAP-and-attachment-td15075220.html) on the PHP Soap Mailing List, it doesn't seem to be possible :

```
Guilhem Martin wrote:
> Hello all,
>
> I was not able to find in the PHP SOAP documentation anything about sending
> attachment.
> So my question is: does PHP SOAP extension support SOAP attachment?
>  

No.

Samisa...
```

But there isn't much detail about it...

Still, I've never seen a file being attached to a SOAP request in PHP