# Zend Framework - Does Zend_Soap_Client supports SwA (Soap With Attachments)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, attachment, wso2

I need SwA (Soap with Attachments) support in php for a project. I can't find a reference in ZF docs about supporting SwA or not. Anybody knows if it is supported?

If not supported, I have heard about WSO2 WSF/PHP which it does support SwA. My question would be... is it possible to integrate both ZF and WSF/PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Pablo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122292/php-soap-client-that-understands-multi-part-messages/1123887#1123887).

ZF's SOAP component is not able to handle multi-part SOAP messages (aka attachments) but I think it's no problem to integrate WSF/PHP into a Zend Framework environment.