# Zend_Soap_Client gets "looks like we got no XML document" error

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I am trying to access a Web Service (SOAP) from a provider. I have not control on the server response. For this I am using, Zend_Soap_Client passing the WDSL and options in the constructor, I can do getFunctions, but when try to access the first Soap method I get

```
[Sender] looks like we got no XML document
```

After looking around and checking the answer I get from the server with soapUI I see that the answer is missing the XML declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="XXXXXXX"?>
```

So, is there aby way to make the Zend_Soap_Client omit the XML validation based in the XML declaration? Assuming that the lacking of the declaration is my problem.

Here is the code I use for this:

```
private $_connection_settings = array('login' => self::API_user, 'pwd' => self::API_password, 'key'=> self::API_Key);


private static $CONNEXION_PARAMS = array(                                            
                                        'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
                                        'encoding'      => 'UTF-8'
                                     );

...

//somewhere in my code: 

$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('http://server_URL?wsdl', self::$CONNEXION_PARAMS);
$response = $client->fistSoapMethod($this->_connection_settings);
```

And response is not assigned.

Thanks!

Comment: Its missing the encoding part only?  Treat it as UTF8.  Your issue might be related to a byte order mark (BOM).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313952/soap-looks-like-we-got-no-xml-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other warnings/errors from your code besides the SOAP Fault?

Not sure it is the WSDL.  Can always try validating the WSDL using an [online tool](http://xmethods.net/ve2/Tools.po).

Have you used getLastResponse() and getLastRequest() methods?  Sounds like you might be sending some garbage at the start of your request.  Another thing I always do when testing is turn off WSDL caching.

`ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);`