# cannot read ascii character 26?

Tags: python, windows, file, unix, character

I wrote a stream in a file in text mode.

```
# python code
f = open("somewhere in my computer","w")
f.write("Hello\nWorld")
f.write(chr(26)) # writing ascii character #26 to file 
f.write("hhh")
f.close()
```

I cannot read bytes after ASCII character #26. I know i should open file with binary mode. Is ascii character #26 `EOF` character. As you know there is not such thing , e.i there is no `EOF` character. So what is problem? Is this an operating system dependent issue? (I try this in Microsoft windows).

Comment: Works for me (OSX). Post the code you're using to read it.

Comment: f = open("somewhere in my computer","r")
t = f.read()
print len(t) # tells 11 and file is at end

Comment: I think in unix like systems there is no difference between text and binary files.

Comment: Probably a windows problem, I get 15.

Comment: This is very ridiculous. Microsoft Windows uses file contents to determine end of file.

Comment: "I know I should open file with binary mode." So do it. In DOS/Windows, files opened in text mode interpret ASCII 26 (control-Z) as an end of file marker, even though there isn't really such thing as an end of file character in the ASCII standard. It's a OS-specific quirk - almost all other modern operating systems do not do this (although there may still be others, so I won't state that definitively)...

Comment: What's so ridiculous of Microsoft to interpret a non-standardized control character using its predominant use at the time as an end-of-file marker in CP/M ([Substitute character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character))? What **is** ridiculous, is you not opening the file in binary mode, full well knowingly that you need to do so.

Comment: @IInspectable this is not my job to worry about file's opening mode when i develop an application. So this is very ridiculous to determine end of file from it's contents. I think in Microsoft Windows i should always open file in binary mode :).

Comment: @HesamQodsi On the other hand, I would argue that when you develop an application, it *is* your job to consider every detail of how that application will interact with whatever environment (operating system, libraries, frameworks, APIs, etc.) it will find itself running in... That would include how to properly open and parse files on that particular environment, as well as a great deal of other details...

Comment: @Hesam The end-of-file marker not only applies to files, but all streams. While this may not appear to provide an immediate advantage for files today, where the file size is recorded alongside the contents, it sure is required for other streams, like STDIN. If you don't want the OS to translate stream contents, open the stream in binary mode. A developer is responsible for making that decision. If you insist that this is not your job, then you are not a developer.

Comment: So tell me, why is there a `chr(26)` in your text file? That's where the problem really lies. Do you think yours is the only Windows program that will fail on this input?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because of the windows. 0x1A is Ctrl-Z, and DOS used that as an end-of-file marker. Python uses the Windows CRT function _wfopen, which implements the "Ctrl-Z is EOF" semantics.
If your file wasn't an exact multiple of 128 bytes, you needed a way to mark the end of the text. This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) implies that the selection of Ctrl-Z was based on an even older convention used by DEC.

Answer (score 1):

This code words for me to open and read the file on Windows. Furthermore, using curses, you can get a "^" representation of any control characters that may be in your file.

```
import curses.ascii

filename = "myfile.txt"
f = open(filename,"w")
f.write("Hello\nWorld")
f.write(chr(26)) # writing ascii character #26 to file 
f.write("hhh")
f.close()

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line2 = [ curses.ascii.unctrl(c) if curses.ascii.iscntrl(c) else c for c in line]
        print("".join(line2))
```

```
Gives output:
Hello^J
World^Zhhh
```

Comment: I take it you're using Python 3? Interesting if so, it implies they no longer rely on the underlying C library for reading files.

Comment: @MarkRansom: this may be related to Python 3 native `str` type being Unicode. As chars are now code points instead of bytes, it makes sense to not interpret  `U+001A` in a special way.

Comment: I came across this again today and did some further testing. Python 3 indeed doesn't stop on 26, I was able to read the entire file using `latin-1` encoding. Even so, it does convert `\r\n` to `\n` as it should. If I use `codecs.open(..., 'r', encoding='latin-1')` in Python 2, it converts to Unicode just like Python 3 but it doesn't stop on 26, but it also *doesn't* convert `\r\n` - it's like a binary file with Unicode conversion.

Comment: @MestreLion it has nothing to do with Unicode, that's just a legacy convention for Windows text files. It's more likely that since Python 3 allows breaking changes, someone decided that the convention is obsolete enough to be discarded.