# Need help removing a Control Character from a string with VB6

Tags: string, vb6

I have the below code searching for the ASCII control Character DEC26 (Substitute). I need to remove it, but it cant find it. This is also a pic from Notepad++ of the text. I have tried using "Open fileName For Binary As #1" but this causes more problems. How can i remove that Chr$(26) (SUB)?

[image]

```
Open fileName For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)                              
    Line Input #1, LineOfText$               
    Alltext$ = Alltext$ & LineOfText$          
Loop

Alltext$ = Replace$(Alltext$, Chr$(26), "") 

Close #1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 follows DOS style file reading and this ASCII control character named SUB (Ctrl+Z) [used as an EOF (end of file) marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786907/cannot-read-ascii-character-26) in DOS.

This loop,

> Do Until EOF(1)

actually stops reading when it encounters a SUB also knows as Chr(26).
You should read the file as a binary or use a FileSystemObject.

This code should work:

```
Dim AllText As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFile = fs.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1, False)

AllText = myFile.ReadAll()
myFile.Close

AllText = Replace$(AllText$, Chr$(26), "")
```

If you add Windows Script Host Object Model reference to your project, you can also use IDE auto-completion and use constant like ForReading:

```
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFile As TextStream
Set myFile = fs.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading, False)
```

instead of CreateObject. First code should also work with VBScript if you remove type definitions and dollars.