# How to trace/debug this error SOAP [message:protected] => looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

The solution doesn't work for me from other links.
I am consuming web services from android using Ksoap2.

Here is my problem I am getting this error.

Here are my server details

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 16:01:16 GMT
X-Varnish: 1781493534
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

1. From PHP client

   ```
   [message:protected] => looks like we got no XML document
   ```
2. From android application using Ksoap2

   ```
   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: '>' actual: '' (position:END_TAG </SOAP-ENV:Envelop>@8:19 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41f06f28)
   ```

My code and web service work fine for all the server. Except the one from Iran. Is there is any encoding issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your webservice is busted and the server (nginx) is throwing an error. All the other errors are just a consequence. You need to fix the webservice by figuring out what is going wrong there. Check the nginx logs and details about whatever is implementing the webservice.

Comment: i generated request response object using wire-shark and found that session id string is "no". I don't find any difference . please see edit. I have compared two responses one is generating response and other is not. But request object seems to be same.

Comment: It still seems to be a server issue and has nothing to do with ksoap2-android. I can not debug it for you....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the web service. It's working on other servers. I installed a new version of the framework (Magento for my case) on Nginx, and now my web service works fine. It may be due to some module interfacing.

Edited:
I have got the same error when I was using different store id to access the data. I was getting the same error looks like we got no XML document.

So I think there is no proper answer to the question. The answer must be how to trace the source of this error.

EDITED [26 June 2016]

This might be the possible answer if you are using Magento. This happens to me once where API throwing a warning before outputting the XML response which was causing the error. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679915/5028508