# extending Php SoapClient to handle multipart response

Tags: php, soap

i am writing a very simple connector to a windows SOAP 1.1 service (WSDL) and using Wsdl2phpgenerator to produce the SoapClient wrappers.  I noticed that these classes use `__soapCall()` instead of `__doRequest()`

Most examples on the web says to extended `__doRequest()` to handle the multipart response (otherwise you get the "looks like no XML error" as a SoapFault)

What is the difference between `__soapCall()` and `__doRequest()` in php SoapClient?

Does `__soapCall()` delegate to `__doRequest()` so overriding `__doRequest()` does the trick anyway?

Is there an example of how to override the `__soapCall()` to handle a multipart return from a Soap service instead of `__doRequest()` since that is what the wsdl2phpgenerator wrappers use?

Answer (score 0):

Override __doRequest() and __soapCall() will use that.

[PHP SOAP client that understands multi-part messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122292/php-soap-client-that-understands-multi-part-messages)

For .NET, there will no `<?xml ...`, so don't key off that.  It is better to key off `<s:Envelope ...`