# PHP SoapClient WSDL request parameter structure

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, schema

I'm a newbie on SOAP webservice. It has a soapserver with test.wsdl provided. I want to get data response from server and write the following PHP script in order to get the result. However, there is an error occurred on script and the error is followings.

**Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrank"' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml".**

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the test.wsdl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="ELevyService" targetNamespace="ELevy.Service" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 

xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="ELevy.Service" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpsBinding_IELevyService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
                <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Strict/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportBinding>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ELevy.Service" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="ELevy.Schema"/>
            <xs:element name="LevyEFrank">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="request" nillable="true" type="q1:LevyEFrankRequest" xmlns:q1="ELevy.Schema"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LevyEFrankResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LevyEFrankResult" nillable="true" type="q2:LevyEFrankResponse" xmlns:q2="ELevy.Schema"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"> 
            <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
            <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
            <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
            <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
            <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="char">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="duration">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
                    <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
                    <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="guid">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ELevy.Schema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="ELevy.Schema">
            <xs:complexType name="LevyEFrankRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="API_KEY" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="RECEIPT_NUMBER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="OUT_BOUND_FARE_PAID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="NAME_OF_TRAVELER_PAYER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="DEPARTURE_DATE" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="LAST_4_DIGIT_OF_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="LevyEFrankRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:LevyEFrankRequest"/>
            <xs:complexType name="LevyEFrankResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ACK_CODE" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ACK_MESSAGE" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RECEIPT_NUMBER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OUT_BOUND_FARE_PAID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NAME_OF_TRAVELER_PAYER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DEPARTURE_DATE" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LAST_4_DIGIT_OF_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FRANK_DATE_TIME" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LEVY_COLLECTION_NUMBER" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LEVY_AMOUNT" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LOW_ACCOUNT_BALANCE_INDICATOR" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LEVY_STAMP" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="LevyEFrankResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:LevyEFrankResponse"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IELevyService_LevyEFrank_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LevyEFrank"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IELevyService_LevyEFrank_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LevyEFrankResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IELevyService">
        <wsdl:operation name="LevyEFrank">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrank" message="tns:IELevyService_LevyEFrank_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrankResponse" message="tns:IELevyService_LevyEFrank_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IELevyService" type="tns:IELevyService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="LevyEFrank">
            <soap:operation soapAction="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrank" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IELevyService" type="tns:IELevyService">
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#BasicHttpsBinding_IELevyService_policy"/>
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="LevyEFrank">
            <soap:operation soapAction="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrank" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ELevyService">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IELevyService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IELevyService">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/ELevyService.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpsBinding_IELevyService" binding="tns:BasicHttpsBinding_IELevyService">
            <soap:address location="https://localhost/ELevyService.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Here is the PHP script index.php :

```
<?php
// initialize soap client
$soapOption = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'location' => 'https://www.elevy-ticf-train.org.hk:8443/ELevyService.svc'
);

$client = new SoapClient('test.wsdl', $soapOption);
$error  = 0;

// request parameters
$soapCallParameters = new stdClass();
$soapCallParameters->API_KEY = '87062F452DD245E89661F5A2E9F8720A';
$soapCallParameters->RECEIPT_NUMBER = '201800001';
$soapCallParameters->OUT_BOUND_FARE_PAID = '105.65';
$soapCallParameters->NAME_OF_TRAVELER_PAYER = "Anonymous";
$soapCallParameters->DEPARTURE_DATE = "2018-12-31";
$soapCallParameters->LAST_4_DIGIT_OF_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER = '3775';

// for debugging
$functions = $client->__getFunctions();
$types = $client->__getTypes();

// debugging status
var_dump($functions);
var_dump($types);
var_dump($client);

try {
    $result = $client->LevyEFrank($soapCallParameters);

} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    $error = 1;
}

if ($error == 1) {
    var_dump($fault->faultcode);
    var_dump($fault->faultstring);
} else {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

var_dump() of PHP script:

```
D:\Wamp64\www\a\index.php:24:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'LevyEFrankResponse LevyEFrank(LevyEFrank $parameters)' 
(length=53)
  1 => string 'LevyEFrankResponse LevyEFrank(LevyEFrank $parameters)' 
(length=53)
D:\Wamp64\www\a\index.php:25:
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'struct LevyEFrank {
 LevyEFrankRequest request;
}' (length=49)
  1 => string 'struct LevyEFrankResponse {
 LevyEFrankResponse LevyEFrankResult;
}' (length=67)
  2 => string 'int char' (length=8)
  3 => string 'duration duration' (length=17)
  4 => string 'string guid' (length=11)
  5 => string 'struct LevyEFrankRequest {
 string API_KEY;
 string RECEIPT_NUMBER;
 string OUT_BOUND_FARE_PAID;
 string NAME_OF_TRAVELER_PAYER;
 string DEPARTURE_DATE;
 string LAST_4_DIGIT_OF_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER;
}' (length=200)
  6 => string 'struct LevyEFrankResponse {
 string ACK_CODE;
 string ACK_MESSAGE;
 string RECEIPT_NUMBER;
 string OUT_BOUND_FARE_PAID;
 string NAME_OF_TRAVELER_PAYER;
 string DEPARTURE_DATE;
 string LAST_4_DIGIT_OF_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER;
 string FRANK_DATE_TIME;
 string LEVY_COLLECTION_NUMBER;
 string LEVY_AMOUNT;
 string LOW_ACCOUNT_BALANCE_INDICATOR;
 base64Binary LEVY_STAMP;
}' (length=366)

D:\Wamp64\www\a\index.php:26:
object(SoapClient)[1]
  public 'location' => string 'https://www.elevy-ticf-train.org.hk:8443/ELevyService.svc' (length=57)
  public '_stream_context' => resource(2, stream-context)
  public '_soap_version' => int 2
  public 'sdl' => resource(4, SOAP SDL)

D:\Wamp64\www\a\index.php:36:string 'HTTP' (length=4)

D:\Wamp64\www\a\index.php:37:string 'Cannot process the message because 
the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; 
action="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrank"' was not the expected 
type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"'.' (length=213)
```

Comment: Now I know how to create the request parameter structure. The last problem is I cannot get the response and the clientsoap fault is shown as below.

**Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="ELevy.Service/IELevyService/LevyEFrank"' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml".**

How can I solve this?

Comment: If I am not wrong, this may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122292/php-soap-client-that-understands-multi-part-messages